# Access Redis CLI inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, redis

I have Redis running inside of a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis).

`docker run --rm -d --name "my_redis" redis`

I'd like to access it via CLI:

If I run `docker exec -it my_redis redis-cli` the console becomes unresponsive until I leave the container (Ctrl + P, Ctrl + Q)

```
C:\Users\Andrzej>docker exec -it my_redis redis-cli
// nothing here until I go Ctrl + P, Ctrl + Q
exec attach failed: error on attach stdin: read escape sequence
C:\Users\Andrzej>
```

If I run `docker exec -it my_redis sh` and then run `redis-cli` from inside of the container it works.

```
C:\Users\Andrzej>docker exec -it my_redis sh
# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set hello world
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get hello
"world"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

My OS is Windows 10.

Is there any way to fix `docker exec -it my_redis redis-cli` behavior?

**UPDATE**

When the console gets unresponsive and I click "arrow up" key exactly 11 times I get the Redis cli. This is 100% reproducible. What kind of voodoo magic is that?

Comment: Try another terminal such as https://conemu.github.io/

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Still the same (cmd, powershell, mingw)

Answer (score 91):

Run a redis container in detached mode:

```
docker run -d redis
```

Run `redis-cli` on it:

```
docker exec -it e0c061a5700bfa400f8f24b redis-cli
```

where `e0c061a5700bfa400f8f24b` is the id of the container.

According to the documentation:

> [Detached (-d)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d)
>
> To start a container in detached mode, you use -d=true or just -d option. By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits, unless you also specify the --rm option. If you use -d with --rm, the container is removed when it exits or when the daemon exits, whichever happens first.

.

> --interactive , -i         Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>
> --tty , -t         Allocate a pseudo-TTY

Comment: I should have mentioned how I instantiate my container. It is detached indeed. Please see the update.

Comment: This command works in (Laravel) Sail as well

Answer (score 24):

1. Run redis container at 6379 port with the name redis in detached
   mode.

**docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis**

2. Run the redis-cli command in the container.

**docker exec -it redis redis-cli**

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not recommended; you should also provide an explanation of what the code does to solve the problem, especially where there are other existing answers.

Answer (score 10):

First of all a container can be a multi command container, which creates option of running CLI inside a container after creating it.
[image]

If you want to start up the CLI you need to some how get in to the container and execute a second command. You need to start up a second program inside  the container.

To run redis-cli into the container, you need to use another docker command-

[image]

**exec** is short for execute and we use it to execute an additional command inside of a container, so write down docker exec then put down dash IT.

**-it** argument allows us to type input directly into the container we then provide the container ID and the the command that we want to execute inside the container.

**sudo docker exec -it container_id redis-cli**

[image]

if you do not use **-it**, you will get kicked directly back, because redis CLI was started up but you did not get the ability to enter in any text.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative approach in addition to the other answers:

```
docker exec -it <your_redis_container_id> sh
```

`#redis-cli` //run redis-cli following the flashing #

127.0.0.1:6379>`your_redis_cli_commands ...`

`#exit` //run exit when you need to exit redis-cli

Answer (score 2):

If you're running redis via Docker on Windows you can open a CLI like this

[image]

Then type `redis-cli` to get the redis client

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to keep the "redis-server" container separate from the "redis-cli" container? You'll have to use docker networking if you want the redis-cli container to be able to speak to the redis-server container.

```
docker network create redis-net
docker run -it --rm --network redis-net --name redis-server -d redis
docker run -it --rm --network redis-net redis redis-cli -h redis-server ping
```

Note: the `--name` (container name) docker flag value is used as the `-h` (redis host) redis-cli flag input.